# Kafka manual offset update using spring boot

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka, and created consumer using Spring boot @kafkalistener.

My use case is once read the message from kafka partition, i need to process and when any exception arise, need to re-process the message after sometime. On exception scenario, I should not update the offset and after server start, i need to process the message again.

Following are the configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka

public class ReceiverConfiguration {

    @Bean
    KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(10);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, String>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap();
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "<some broker configuration>");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "6000");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomDeserializer.class);
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "Test-Consumer-Group");
        propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        return propsMap;
    }


    @Bean
    public Listener listener() {
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%% Initializing Listener %%%%%%%");
        return new Listener();
    }
}
```

Following are the listener class

```
public class Listener {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Listener.class);

    public CountDownLatch getCountDownLatch1() {
        return countDownLatch1;
    }

    private CountDownLatch countDownLatch1 = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "topic")
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, CustomObject> record, Acknowledgment ack) throws Exception{
        logger.info("******** 1 message: "+record);
        //ack.acknowledge();
    }
}
```

scenario 1: During Consumer service is running, when producer sending the message, Listener class reading the message and Not updating the offset, till this part looks good. If i Stop the consumer, offset is updated in the consumer group.
Problem: Should not update the offset during server stop scenario. Once my back-end processing issue is resolved, when i restart my consumer service, I need to consume the message again only when the offset is not committed. But here offset is committed and there is no chance i can consumer the message from partition again.

scenario 2: Assuming my consumer service is down, Producer sending message to Topic partition, can see offset is not incremented and lag is 1. Still service is not enabled with ack.acknowledge(), i.e. code is commented out only, even though offset is committed in the consumer group.
Problem: Till I am acknowledging the offset, should not commit the offset. Problem noticed in server start.

Please help me resolving the issue, was not able to find proper redirection.

Appreciate your help

Comment: 1) when your auto.commit is turned off (set to false), it is your responsibility to commit whenever you want. So, during shutdown signal you can first complete you processing and then gracefully shutdown, which means you need to have that logic in you consumer which is a Thread I believe. 2) Is the `Acknowledgment` Spring API? as I don't think its from Kafka client API. And I'm guessing its responsible for committing the offset to Kafka for that particular Listener. Your statement is not clear when you say - "Still service is not enabled with `ack.acknowledge()`"

Comment: 1) taking decisions to shutdown the server is to stop processing the particular message and i need to hold the offset  and lag. for ex: my consumer service is consume and post to another service. once the downstream service is recovered and restart my consumer service, i need to re-process the message again, because my offset is not updated. this use case, i dont want to process the message completed before graceful shutdown.

Comment: 2) Using spring framework kafka API, org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment. during server startup, i see the offset committed, even though i did not acknowledged. Only place the offset is not committed during when the consumer service is running. During server stop and start i see the offset is updated.